# Intellisense for WebForms doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I use Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.7). I created new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) with web forms. But in code behind “Find All References” doesn’t work for setter. And in .aspx-file I can’t “drill down” to user control definition. It seems like a plain text.

I can’t use a previous visual studio version. My current project contains a lot of web forms and also projects with PackageReference format

I had installed visual studio 2017 before. But I unistalled it according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2017 Also I several times have reinstalled visual studio 2019 but problem remains

Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Create ASP.NET WEB Application (.Net Framework) C#
2. Select Web Forms Template
3. At ViewSwitcher.aspx.cs file I have added public property

```
        public string SomeProp { get; set; }
```

4. At Site.Mobile.Master file I have added value. Here intellisense works. It suggests property SomeProp.

```
<friendlyUrls:ViewSwitcher SomeProp="someValue" runat="server" />
```

5. Build.
6. Return to ViewSwitcher.aspx.cs. I do right mouse click on `set` of `SomeProp` and click "Find All References". But it doesn't show using from Site.Mobile.Master.

It is too difficult make any refactoring and rename without it

Maybe, visual studio have never had such feature. Previously I have used Resharper but now I can't use it.

The same true for visual studio 2017. windows 10

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. A good question.

Comment: With "Drill down", do you talk about the F12 key?. With me, both the F12 key (in aspx and code behind) and the "Find all References" in the code behind do work, in a WebForms project with .NET 4.6.2 in my case. I have Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.6.5. Maybe the "Enterprise" does make a difference. And oh, I also use ReShaper, but it should make no difference, as the features you are talking about are not ReSharper's.

Comment: Yes it is because Resharper. I also can with Resharper

Comment: Ok, then. Please post this finding as an answer to your own question. It's regarded as good etiquette here, because actually it is an answer.

Comment: No, it is not answer. I don't want use Resharper

Comment: My opinion is that many things change at MS and VS2019. You should think of moving to .net core ... also webform doesn't sound safe for me ...

Comment: check out these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474785/visual-studio-2019-go-to-definition-and-intellisense-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try the following suggestions:

**1)** disable any third party vs installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

**2)** [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

**3)** run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**.

**4)** close VS, delete all the folders `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx` to initialize your VS.

**also**, for your project, you should delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of your project.

[image]

**Besides**, if you still cannot get what you want,  please click `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe` to clear all vs versions strongly, their registry information and data info.

**Then**, reinstall the VS again. If you have tried this step, then, you should try to turn off any antivirus software, other third party windows programs.

**Update 1**

**Actually**, it is quite strange. As to help you further, I have [reported the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1245687/why-the-property-cannot-be-found-under-find-all-re.html) and you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention. And I hope the Team will give you a satisfactory reply.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. It strange. For protected propetries inside .ascx "Find All References" works, but it doesn't work for setter of public properties when I set that property in some .aspx

Comment: Quite strange. Did  you try to use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start VS to test the issue. Besides,And could you please provide some sample code and several steps to help us reproduce this issue? And it could be helpful.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: It seems that when I search `SomeProp` user control property by right-click on `Find All References`, it cannot find it on `Site.Mobile.Master` page, I faced such situation and I am investigating it. And I will report to the team.

Comment: @user2768921, I have reported the issue on our DC Forum. See update from my answer. And you can check it.