# Auto completion of classes from another project in the same solution doesn't work

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

I will reformulate my question because Visual Studio 2019 updated and the problem is back.

Here's the problem:

In my solution, I have 2 projects. The first one, let's say P1, is a vb.net class library. The second, P2, is a normal C# windows application.

P1 references are added in P2 and I can successfully use P1's classes in my P2.

BUT, the auto completion and Intellisense doesn't see the P1 classes.

Problems encountered :

- No autocompletion
- Can't navigate to symbol under the caret
- Errors within these lines of code where a class of P1 is used doesn't show up in the Error List (but prevent building project)
- No colors in the code (See images)

What I have
[image]
What I want (Ignore the theme)
[image]

I hope this is enough information. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe I'm miss-understanding your question but I believe that to be the default behavior.  Does your IntelliSense work at all?  Maybe you need to run a repair on your VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem :

Doing this :

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General. Make sure “Auto List Members” is checked. Also, make sure “Parameter Information” is checked.

And then this:

- Close Visual Studio
- Delete .vs folder (it is a hidden folder inside the folder which contains the solution *.sln)
- Start Visual Studio

Solved the problem for me. Thanks to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474785/visual-studio-2019-go-to-definition-and-intellisense-not-working)