# Why doesn't the <asp:Label> component display Hint for Style property in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

When I enter a space key in the `<asp:Label .....  ></asp:Label>` code , the VS 2019 will popup a window to display all properties for the `<asp:Label>` component , so I can select a property to custmize it,  you can see Image A.

The Code A is correct, I customize the `Style` property, but I find all properties listed the popup window (Image A ) doesn't display the `Style` property, why?

**Code A**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Info"  Style="margin-top:10px;" ></asp:Label>
```

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: This could be due to a VS 2019 issue or bug. Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474785/visual-studio-2019-go-to-definition-and-intellisense-not-working).